# using python v2 azure event grid output binding and keeps complaining about function.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-eventgrid, azure-triggers

I'm literally using microsoft azure official documentation for event grid output binding. and this is there code. I'm using python V2 which doesn't rely on function.json, however i keep getting errors on function.json, why?

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import datetime

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="eventgrid_output")
@app.route(route="eventgrid_output")
@app.event_grid_output(
    arg_name="outputEvent",
    topic_endpoint_uri="MyEventGridTopicUriSetting",
    topic_key_setting="MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")
def eventgrid_output(eventGridEvent: func.EventGridEvent, 
         outputEvent: func.Out[func.EventGridOutputEvent]) -> None:

    logging.log("eventGridEvent: ", eventGridEvent)

    outputEvent.set(
        func.EventGridOutputEvent(
            id="test-id",
            data={"tag1": "value1", "tag2": "value2"},
            subject="test-subject",
            event_type="test-event-1",
            event_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            data_version="1.0"))
```

This is the exception i keep getting!

> Exception: FunctionLoadError: cannot load the test function: the following parameters are declared in Python but not in function.json: {'eventGridEvent'}

Easily runing since it;s on their official page

Answer (score 1):

> I'm literally using microsoft azure official documentation for event grid output binding. and this is there code. I'm using python V2 which doesn't rely on function.json, however i keep getting errors on function.json,

Initially I am also getting same errors by followed the [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-python#configuration-1) eventgrid output binding.

- I have added the trigger to the given code. it works fine. check below:

**function code:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="eventgrid_out")
@app.event_grid_trigger(arg_name="eventGridEvent")
@app.event_grid_output(
    arg_name="outputEvent",
    topic_endpoint_uri="your-endpoint",
    topic_key_setting="your-topic key")
def eventgrid_output(eventGridEvent: func.EventGridEvent,
        outputEvent: func.Out[func.EventGridOutputEvent]) -> None:

    logging.info("eventGridEvent: %s", eventGridEvent)

    outputEvent.set(
        func.EventGridOutputEvent(
            id="test-id",
            data={"tag1": "value1", "tag2": "value2"},
            subject="test-subject",
            event_type="test-event-1",
            event_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            data_version="1.0"))
```

The above code executed successfully. check below:

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: were you able to have the output topic as managed identity without the keys?

Comment: thanks! did you manage to get managed identity to work instead with v2?

Comment: I have tried with topic key and endpoint. resolved the errors which occurs about function.json.

Comment: I'm trying to use managed identity but dont know what to put in the topic_key_setting="your-topic key", zero documentation for v2

Comment: I think with managed identity not possible someone raised a bug on this issue.